Weapons of mass destruction cracking Earth's crust, unleashing zombies
I'm looking for a "Horror" Movie, I've tried to find it again but it seems impossible on my own.
The Movie starts with a War and what happened before it.
There are I think it was 4 companys who used super weapons ( maybe just 1 who did, anyway ) it cracked the earth unleashing a ton of ( i'd call them zombies ) from underground ( earth core ). However they couldn't hold out against them and later on they're trying to get people to safety ( but ofc can't take everyone ). A group of Soldiers who fought in that war went to help some people out who couldn't afford to get on the aircraft. ( beating up the soldiers guarding it ) then they go underground through a small entrance, maybe it was an old elevator where there are ruins and tons of "zombies".
Wasn't one of the best movies but I kinda liked it. Would like to watch it again.
Anything close or maybe not so close that pops to mind would be helpful.
Only part I'm 100% certain about was the war and the super weapon that blasted a huge hole in the ground where those "zombies" came out of.

Mutant Chronicles, (2008):

At the end of the Ice Age, The Machine came from outer space with the
  purpose to change men into mutants. However, a hero defeated the
  device and a great seal was laid over The Machine. In 2707, the
  depleted world is ruled by four Corporations: Mishima, Bauhaus,
  Capitol and Imperial that are in a constant state of war. During a
  battle between Capitol and Bauhaus, the great seal is broken and The
  Machine works again transforming soldiers and civilians into hordes of
  mutants.


ffs that's it :D thank you.
